# How do I fix a "could not symlink" error when running `brew link automake`?

Tags: homebrew, automake

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/aclocal/README
/usr/local/share/aclocal is not writable.

You can try again using:   brew link automake
```

When I try again it shows the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar error:

```
$ brew link pkg-config
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28...
Error: Could not symlink share/aclocal/pkg.m4
/usr/local/share/aclocal is not writable.
```

I fixed this using: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/`